# Weird issue with sticky navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My sticky navigation works like so:
If I scroll down, it changes to the sticky one, and if I scroll up, it changes to the default one. However, the problem I encounter is that when I 'refresh' the page, I start off on the first page, and on that page the navigation is still 'sticky'. Then I gotta scroll down, and scroll back up to make it it's original state?

[image]

When I refresh, it is the sticky nav on the front page, this is the problem.

### [image]

Then after I scroll down, and then up, the navigation becomes proper. THIS is the navigation I want when I refresh, but for some reason it is the old one.

```
      <nav class="sticky">
        <div class="row">
            <img src="resources/img/logo.png" class="logo">
            <img src="resources/img/logo-nav.png" class="logo-black">

            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

            </ul>


        </div>

    </nav>


.sticky .logo {
    display: none;
}

.sticky .logo-black {
    display: block;
}

.logo
{
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 25%;


}

.logo-black {
    display: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

That is my basic navigation. logo-black refers to the 'sticky nav logo'.
I believe my formatting and html is correct, so why should this error occur? It's not a jQuery error, I dont believe so, since without jquery it does the same thing.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.js-section-about').waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction == 'down'){
            $('nav').addClass('sticky');
        }
        else {
            $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
        }
    }, {
  offset: '60px;' 
})

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<nav class="sticky">` to `<nav>` in your HTML. This way, the `.sticky` class will only be added by your jQuery on scroll. As it stands right now, you're counting on your code to *remove* the `.sticky` class on page load and add it again when you hit the waypoint.

Comment: if i remove it then how will it know what sticky means?

Comment: @KSplitX Did you try the suggestion? Your document will know what `.sticky` means because your CSS defines it. The element doesn't need to be that way on load to keep its meaning.

Comment: thanks it worked! i just wanted to know 'how' it would work, thanks for clearing it up